User role added doesn't appear
I am doing a flutter app and at the register page I want to add user role. ( one to be client, another one business) . The problem is that I get some errors and I don't understand what I done wrong in implementation .
    class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

var options = [
  'Customer',
  'Business',
];
var _currentItemSelected = 'Customer';
var rool = "Customer";

TextEditingController _usernameController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
bool isSigningUp = false;
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final FirebaseAuthServices _auth = FirebaseAuthServices();

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _usernameController.dispose();
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, left: 30, right: 30),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Logo(),
              SignUpButton(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 62,
                width: 350,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                      )),
                  onPressed: _signUp,
                  child: Text(
                    'Sign Up',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              LoginButton(),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }

  void _signUp() async {
    String email = _emailController.text;
    String password = _passwordController.text;
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      await _auth
          .signUpWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then((value) => {postDetailsToFirestore(email, rool)})
          .catchError((e) {});
    }

    //   User? user = await _auth.signUpWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    //   if (user != null) {
    //     print("User is successfully created");
    //     Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
    //   } else {
    //     print("Some error happend");
    //   }
  }

  postDetailsToFirestore(String email, String rool) async {
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    var user = _auth.currentUser;
    CollectionReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    ref.doc(user!.uid).set({'email': _emailController.text, 'rool': rool});
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
  }
}

class SignUpButton extends StatefulWidget{
   @override
  _SignupButtonState createState() => _SignupButtonState();
}
class _SignupButtonState extends State<SignUpButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Form(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
              child: FormContainerWidget(
                controller: _usernameController,
                hintText: "Username",
                isPasswordField: false,

                // prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person)),
              )),
          Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
              child: FormContainerWidget(
                controller: _emailController,
                hintText: "Email",
                isPasswordField: false,

                // prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person)),
              )),
          Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
              child: FormContainerWidget(
                controller: _passwordController,
                hintText: "Password",
                isPasswordField: true,

                // prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person)),
              )),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Container(
              height: 62,
              width: 350,
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
              child: DropdownButton(
                  isExpanded: true,
                  value: dropdownvalue,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                  items: options.map((String items) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(value: items, child: Text(items));
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (newValueSelected) {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentItemSelected = newValueSelected!;
                      rool = newValueSelected!;
                    });
                  },
                  value: _currentItemSelected)),
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.email,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),
          ])
        ])),
      ],
    );
  }
}

And here are the errors in the code


Does anyone know what I should add or change? where I should add that value? or current user?

Error of setState can be resolved by making SignUpButton widget as StatefulWidget because StatelessWidgetdoesn't have setState method

hovering your mouse over the red underlined words tells you exactly what's wrong

https://imgur.com/a/vcYQNfn

https://imgur.com/a/rzcSPaE

To help you with getting the current user information, could you please share your service file? Alternatively, you can use the following approach:
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FirebaseAuthServices {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  get currentUser => _auth.currentUser;

  //SIGN UP METHOD
  Future signUpWithEmailAndPassword(String email,  String password) async {
    try {
      await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      return null;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }

  //SIGN IN METHOD
  Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      return null;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }

  //SIGN OUT METHOD
  Future signOut() async {
    await _auth.signOut();

    print('signout');
  }
}

If you want to user from firebase so you can use :
 User? user =  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;


Thank youuu! I still receive an error at value

can you please share your service file.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78668761/sign-up-page-doesnt-root-to-the-homepage
