Sign Up page doesn't root to the homepage
I am doing the registration page to my app and I have 2 types of user Client and Business. The problem is that I added this signup method and it is not working, after I click on Sign Up, nothing happens ... what I should do or change to the code? the before code // for signUp worked but I didn't include those details of user role(business/client)
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

var options = [
  'Customer',
  'Business',
];
var _currentItemSelected = 'Customer';
var rool = "Customer";

TextEditingController _usernameController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
bool isSigningUp = false;
@override
final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final FirebaseAuthServices _auth = FirebaseAuthServices();

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _usernameController.dispose();
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, left: 30, right: 30),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Logo(),
              SignUpButton(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 62,
                width: 350,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                      )),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      signUp(_emailController.text, _passwordController.text,
                          rool);
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Sign Up',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              LoginButton(),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }

  void signUp(String email, String password, String rool) async {
    CircularProgressIndicator();
    if (_formkey.currentState!.validate()) {
      await _auth
          .signUpWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then((value) => {postDetailsToFirestore(email, rool)})
          .catchError((e) {});
    }
  }

  //  User? user = await _auth.signUpWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

//   if (user != null) {
//     print("User is successfully created");
//     Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
//   } else {
//     print("Some error happend");
//   }

  postDetailsToFirestore(String email, String rool) async {
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    var user = _auth.currentUser;
    CollectionReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    ref.doc(user!.uid).set({'email': _emailController.text, 'rool': rool});
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
  }
}

class SignUpButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignupButtonState createState() => _SignupButtonState();
}

class _SignupButtonState extends State<SignUpButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Form(
            key: _formkey,
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
                  child: FormContainerWidget(
                    controller: _usernameController,
                    hintText: "Username",
                    isPasswordField: false,

                    // prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person)),
                  )),
              Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
                  child: FormContainerWidget(
                    controller: _emailController,
                    hintText: "Email",
                    isPasswordField: false,

                    // prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person)),
                  )),
              Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
                  child: FormContainerWidget(
                    controller: _passwordController,
                    hintText: "Password",
                    isPasswordField: true,

                    // prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person)),
                  )),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                  height: 62,
                  width: 350,
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                    dropdownColor: Colors.white,
                    isDense: true,
                    isExpanded: false,
                    iconEnabledColor: Colors.white,
                    focusColor: Colors.white,
                    items: options.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: dropDownStringItem,
                        child: Text(
                          dropDownStringItem,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (newValueSelected) {
                      setState(() {
                        _currentItemSelected = newValueSelected!;
                        rool = newValueSelected;
                      });
                    },
                    value: _currentItemSelected,
                  )),
              Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.email,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                  ])
            ])),
      ],
    );
  }
}

here it's a photo of the outcome error
